# How can I set the directory of a MongoDB database in a Java application?

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I recently decided to learn the foundamentals of using MongoDB in  Java applications but I have some problems and doubts to resolve. I hope someone can help me.
I wrote a little Java application to read and write data in a local Mongo database (I'm using **mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar** on Windows 10).
I have installed MongoDB in the directory *C:\Program Files\MongoDB*.
Can anyone tell me if is possible to create my **test** database in a specific directory (for example *D:\Database*)? Thank you.

```
package test;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MongoDBJDBC 
{
   public static void main( String args[] ) 
   {
      try
      {
         // Connection to the MongoDB server
         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017);

         // Connection to the database
         MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
         System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The path MongoDB uses to store your database files is specified by your `--dbpath` arg when running your mongod. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-dbpath.  Your application doesn't have any control over that.

Comment: Nor "should" any such program have such an effect. It would only matter in such instances where you "actually intended" on some embedded design to "start" and "stop" a `mongod` process as a controlled dependency of the application. But this would not be a general recommended design, and you should simply treat it as a remote service you connect to at a supplied address.